# Does the flow of Divine goodness from a Bracha flow upwards or horizontally?

Tags: blessing, tov-goodness

In short: I once read an explanation of Ramchal that HaShem didn't create the world for His own benefit, because He doesn't need anything, so all that He had created has been created for 'another'. A lot of commentaries speak about HaShem being Koelo Tov, (He is complete, absolute, perfect etc. Good). And Ramak teaches that one who is inherently good, does good. So the conclusion of all this was that HaShem created to world to bestow His Goodness.

Anyway, now I came across of an explanation regarding the term 'Bracha': which stated that this term is related with the term Breicha, meaning a flowing stream, or source of water; and by such it is interpreted as a stream of Divine goodness flowing downward into the world.

HaShem is the source of all blessings. When we say *Birkat HaMazon*, the grace after the meal, we acknowledge that all our blessings emanate from Him, and we thank Him for all the goodness we receive on a constant basis. When we express a bracha, it facilitates a Divine flow of blessings upon us from Above. We acknowledge that all our blessings in life come from the Ultimate source of all blessings.

All our brachot (often recited starting with the words Baruch Atah) seem to affirm this view. But looking at the Tenach we see HaShem bless man, man bless HaShem, and man bless man. How do I need to understand this stream of divine goodness? How is it able to flow from man to G'd and man to man?

Comment: Found some commentaries of Ramchal regard the reason why HaShem made us and all of His creation; 'so that He could bestow His goodness, overflowing abundance'. In Kabbalist thinking, the whole point to creation on one level is to be the recipient of God’s goodness. In Genesis, God is continually seeing the process of creation and Creation itself as being the embodiment of good. The entire universe is predicated on the foundation of good and the divine intention is therefore to continue to provide goodness to all realms in order to support that underlying base.

Comment: The concept of Shefa is a particularly important one in Kabbalist teaching; one that is central in understanding how the universe in general and humanity in particular are sustained. The principle implies the concept that like flows to like. God creates the world as the supreme manifestation of good and then sustains it constantly with the flow of goodness. Could someone explain me how all of the views I gave so far define the concept of making/giving Brachot?

Comment: Blessing – “berakha” – means bringing down Divine influence or abundance (shefa) into the world. A prerequisite for achieving this is an acknowledgment on the part of those who receive this gift that its source is from God. This acknowledgment causes further Divine influence or abundance to descend into the world, and the cycle continues. A person who recites a blessing is thanking God for the good that He has given, and in the wake of this acknowledgment the person becomes worthy and deserving of further and continues kindness from God.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear that shepha beracha comes from Hashem since Hashem handed the koach ha'beracha to the avos.

Es asher tevorech etc.

I.e. shepha is like a tide of water that comes down through the generations which has caused our continuation till today.

The question is how do you tap into it?

Probably by identifying with the cause of the continuation of klal yisrael in some way.